# How to display information of a line such as width, color,... so it can be copied exactly?

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2010, shapes

I am using Visio 2010 and I have a Visio file with two lines, round corners as below. I have one question hope anyone could help me out.

How to show the information of the line such as the width, color,... so I can copy exactly the information for my drawing?

Here is [the Visio file](https://ufile.io/zhxi9) for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to look at the shape's shapesheet.

Ensure Developer mode is enabled (in Options), select the shape, then use

**Developer** -> **Show Shapesheet**